# is registarion page compulsory for the admin section of any project?

Tags: language-agnostic

i have a confusion, i am creating a shopping cart, i am having two sections one is customer and one is the admin. For customer section i have created registration form and the login page. But i am confused with the admin section, for admin section i also need to create the registration page or i should directly create the login page and for each admin i should manually do data base entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

**What do you want the process of adding a new admin to be?**

- If there's a registration page you don't want anyone to just show up and sign up as an admin, so you would need some approval / review process to allow people to become administrators.
- If it requires manual database entry, that would limit who could create administrators, but may be cumbersome and awkward to manually get new admin information.
- Another approach would be to let the admin register 1st as a normal user, and seperately have a page to assign the administrator privilige to other users.  This page, of course, would only be accessible by administrators.  That way your admins would sign up normally, then later an existing admin could turn on their 'admin' flag.

Comment: Sir, your third point is not clear to me, please elaborate me a bit on this....This is my first web site i am creating and i have been stuck on this point. initially  i thought to make a registration and login page which user willbe unaware about in terms of web link..only admin will be knowing that what url he/she should type to register as admin, but i thought in case if some user comes to know this then what, all will ruin, so what should i do to achieve this?

Comment: Hello sir are you there? I am in dire need to solve this problem help me with this..a few points i have mentioned int the above answer.are those the right approach?

Comment: The idea is to create a page that before anything checks that the user requesting the page is in fact an administrator.  On this page, the administrator can select other users to be assigned 'administrator' roles.  They will be presented with a list of users and after they select/deselect some you will need to inspect the selection and set update your database so that those users become administrator.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a registration page, that would mean that users can go and register themselves as admin?

I'd have a user administration tool in the admin section, and then give some users an "admin role" allowing them to login to the admin section. Of course, you'll have to start with some "Super Administrator" to log in to the admin section the first time.

Comment: yes u are true, so what should i do make admin privileges page because i am afraid if some body else access it and register to the page then he/she will become admin. but i want stop him from becoming admin..admin should be that guy only who really have privileges so for that what should i do please let me know

Comment: how can i make that "Super Administrator"?

Comment: you mean to say that, i should make a field in database user table setRole and byDefault i should make it customer, and i want some one to make admin then i should set that default field to admin manually in data base, and from a common login page i should check for role and user name, pass then i should redirect according to that and in that case both admin and customer will be sharing a common table for registration.... so is it the approach you want to tel me, am i correct please explain me how to rid of this problem